# Javascript function not called from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script with two methods one that's submits a form with Ajax

```
function saveCustomer(){
  $('#createCustomer').submit(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
   var $inputs = $('#createCustomer :input');
   var values = {};
   $inputs.each(function() {
       values[this.name] = $(this).val();
   });
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    })
    $.ajax({
      url: '/customer',
      type : 'POST',
      data : values,
      success : function(data){
          //check if controller validation send customer exist
          if(data.confirmation){
            $("#confirmation").show();
          }
          else{
            $('#createCustomer :input').val('');
            $("#customer").hide();

            //assign values to success modal

              $('#firstName').val(data.customer.firstName);
              $('#lastName').val(data.customer.lastName);
              $('#street').val(data.address.street);
              $('#businessName').val(data.customer.businessName);

            $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
          }
      },
      error : function(error){
          $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And a function that adds another input to the form and calls the first function

```
$('#proceedWithSave').on('click', function(){
  var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "proceed");

  $('#createCustomer').append($(input));
  saveCustomer();
});
```

Now the second function is called successfully because it adds the new input but the first function is not called because no ajax call is made.

Any ideas on what can be wrong here?

Comment: The first function creates a submit handler, it doesn't submit anything.

Comment: saveCustomer is creating a new binding on the createCustomer element.  What you are really after is an invocation of that function you are binding as the event handler.  I would suggest extracting that out into a named function, give that named function to the event binding, and in the case of the other click handler, call that named function directly instead of going through the saveCustomer method.

Comment: Calling `saveCustomer()` doesn't submit an AJAX request, so that's not really an indication of success or failure for that function.  Does it successfully add the submit handler?

Comment: @Taplar Can you do some modifications to the code so that I can make this work. The saveCustomer() is called by the onclick attribute in a button

Comment: @reidi_qyrku: That depends on what you mean by "make this work".  What *should* your code be doing?  Currently it seems to be working just fine for what it was written to do.  Do you want to attach the submit handler and then invoke that event?  Do you want to just invoke the function used to handle that event?  Do you not want a submit handler at all?  Something else?

Comment: @David Basically I want that when the second method is called to add the new input (as it does) and resubmit the form with the new input

Comment: @reidi_qyrku: You can trigger the submit event on the form with: `$('#createCustomer').trigger('submit');`  Though it's still not really clear if you still intend to add that submit handler in that function the way you currently are.  You have to add it somewhere, otherwise it won't exist.  But if you're calling that function multiple times then you certainly don't want to add it over and over like that.

Comment: @David Seems like $('#createCustomer').trigger('submit'); did the work or as I used it $('#createCustomer').submit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to submit the `form`, using Ajax, on click of `$('#proceedWithSave')`...

So just remove the `$('#createCustomer').submit(function(ev) {` line and its closing `});` bracket.

```
function saveCustomer(){
  //$('#createCustomer').submit(function(ev) {
   //ev.preventDefault();
   $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
   var $inputs = $('#createCustomer :input');
   var values = {};
   $inputs.each(function() {
       values[this.name] = $(this).val();
   });
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    })
    $.ajax({
      url: '/customer',
      type : 'POST',
      data : values,
      success : function(data){
          //check if controller validation send customer exist
          if(data.confirmation){
            $("#confirmation").show();
          }
          else{
            $('#createCustomer :input').val('');
            $("#customer").hide();

            //assign values to success modal

              $('#firstName').val(data.customer.firstName);
              $('#lastName').val(data.customer.lastName);
              $('#street').val(data.address.street);
              $('#businessName').val(data.customer.businessName);

            $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
          }
      },
      error : function(error){
          $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
      }
    });
  //});
}

$('#proceedWithSave').on('click', function(){
  var input = $("<input>")
               .attr("type", "hidden")
               .attr("name", "proceed");

  $('#createCustomer').append($(input));
  saveCustomer();
});
```